# How to get multiple conditions in m:n relations with multiple joins?

Tags: mysql

I have to write a complex query to get products in MySQL with multiple conditions and stucking on relations with multiple conditions.

The database structure is built from Typo3. At the moment I have 4 joins with multiple conditions. Everything is working fine but the last line of my SQL is the problem. But I can't get any solution.

```sql
SELECT p.uid
FROM tx_myext_domain_model_product p
         JOIN tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung w
              ON p.uid = w.product
         JOIN sys_category_record_mm ck
              ON p.uid = ck.uid_foreign
         JOIN sys_category_record_mm cc
              ON p.uid = cc.uid_foreign
         JOIN sys_category_record_mm cw
              ON w.uid = cw.uid_foreign
WHERE p.season IN(1,'')
  AND p.type = "herbizid"
  AND ck.uid_local = 2
  AND ck.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_product"
  AND ck.fieldname = "culture"
  AND cc.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_product"
  AND cc.fieldname = "chemicals"
  AND cw.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung"
  AND cw.uid_local IN (2, 395, 257)  
  AND w.grad = 6;

#  and wirkung with cw.uid_local = 2 should have w.grad = 6
#  and wirkung with cw.uid_local = 395 should have w.grad = 6  
#  and wirkung with cw.uid_local = 257 should have w.grad in range from 1 to 6
```

The 'productwirkung' should have the category 2, 395 and 257 and the 'productwirkung' with the category 2 and 395 should have the grad 6.

I know, with this last line I can't get anything...

**EDIT**

I cannot add `w.grad = 6` because the product should have a productwirkung with the category 257 too with grad 1 - 6. One product has multiple relations with productwirkung. So if there is a product with productwirkung 2 with grad = 6, productwirkung 395 with grad = 6 and productwirkung 257 with grad = 3 I want this product. If I ask for `... cw.uid_local IN (2, 395, 257) AND w.grad = 6` The product wont be selected because productwirkung 257 doesn't has w.grad = 6.

Comment: `uid_local` cannot be `= 2 and 395` on the same row. Try,  `c2.uid_local in (2,395) and w.grad = 6` and remove the second condition.

Comment: I want the products with wirkung uid_local 2, uid_local 395 and uid_local 257 but the wirkung with uid_local 2 and 395 should has grad = 6. The wirkung with 257 can has the grad between 1 and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your last two where conditions are conflicting. They state that a row **has** to contain the `cw.uid_local` of either 2, 395 or 257 **AND** must have the ID 2 **AND** 395 in a single row. If you rewrite the last two lines as an OR conditional, you should get the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT `p`.`uid`
FROM `tx_myext_domain_model_product` `p`
     INNER JOIN `tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung` `w`
                ON `p`.`uid` = w.product
     INNER JOIN `sys_category_record_mm` `ck`
                ON `ck`.`tablenames` = "tx_myest_domain_model_product"
                    AND `p`.`uid` = ck.uid_foreign
                    AND `ck`.`fieldname` = "culture"
     INNER JOIN `sys_category_record_mm` `cc`
                ON `cc`.`tablenames` = "tx_myext_domain_model_product"
                    AND `p`.`uid` = cc.uid_foreign
                    AND `cc`.`fieldname` = "chemicals"
     INNER JOIN `sys_category_record_mm` `cw`
                ON `cw`.`tablenames` = "tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung"
                    AND `w`.`uid` = cw.uid_foreign
WHERE ((`p`.`season` = "1") OR (`p`.`season` = ""))
  AND (`p`.`type` = "herbizid")
  AND (`ck`.`uid_local` = "2")
  AND ((`cw`.`uid_local` IN (2, 395) AND `w`.`grad` = 6) OR `cw`.`uid_local` = 257);
```

**EDIT**

Upon reading your edit, I think you'd best be served with subqueries, seeing as your required conditions are conflicting for a single query.

If you want the products where **ALL** conditions are met (products with "children" that have a (uid_local of 2 AND grad of 6) **AND** "children" with (uid_local of 395 AND grad of 6) **AND** "children" with (uid_local of 257 AND grad between 1 and 6)), I would suggest using inner joins with subqueries to constrict your data to the "child cases":

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.uid
FROM tx_myext_domain_model_product p
  ### WHERE cw.uid_local = 2 AND w.grad = 6
  JOIN (
    SELECT p_1.uid
    FROM tx_myext_domain_model_product p_1
    JOIN tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung w_1
      ON p_1.uid = w_1.product
    JOIN sys_category_record_mm cw_1
      ON w_1.uid = cw_1.uid_foreign
    WHERE cw_1.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung"
      AND cw_1.uid_local = 2
      AND w_1.grad = 6
  ) p1 ON p1.uid = p.uid
  ### WHERE cw.uid_local = 395 AND w.grad = 6
  JOIN (
    SELECT p_2.uid
    FROM tx_myext_domain_model_product p_2
    JOIN tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung w_2
      ON p_2.uid = w_2.product
    JOIN sys_category_record_mm cw_2
      ON w_2.uid = cw_2.uid_foreign
    WHERE cw_2.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung"
      AND cw_2.uid_local = 395
      AND w_2.grad = 6
  ) p2 ON p2.uid = p.uid
  ### WHERE cw.uid_local = 257 AND w.grad BETWEEN 1 AND 6
  JOIN (
    SELECT p_3.uid
    FROM tx_myext_domain_model_product p_3
    JOIN tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung w_3
      ON p_3.uid = w_3.product
    JOIN sys_category_record_mm cw_3
      ON w_3.uid = cw_3.uid_foreign
    WHERE cw_3.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung"
      AND cw_3.uid_local = 257
      AND w_3.grad BETWEEN 1 AND 6
  ) p3 ON p3.uid = p.uid
  JOIN tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung w
    ON p.uid = w.product
  JOIN sys_category_record_mm ck
    ON p.uid = ck.uid_foreign
  JOIN sys_category_record_mm cc
    ON p.uid = cc.uid_foreign
  JOIN sys_category_record_mm cw
    ON w.uid = cw.uid_foreign
WHERE p.season IN(1,'')
  AND p.type = "herbizid"
  AND ck.uid_local = 2
  AND ck.tablenames = "tx_myest_domain_model_product"
  AND ck.fieldname = "culture"
  AND cc.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_product"
  AND cc.fieldname = "chemicals";
```

Comment: The correct way but not perfect...  `#  and wirkung with cw.uid_local = 2 has to be w.grad = 6
#  and wirkung with cw.uid_local = 395 has to be w.grad = 6  
#  and wirkung with cw.uid_local = 257 has to be w.grad in range from 1 to 6`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `uid_local` is unique, it can not **by definition** be both `2` and `395`

I guess you wanted to go for

```
  ...
  AND ((`cw`.`uid_local` = 2 AND `w`.`grad` = 6) OR (`cw`.`uid_local` = 395 AND `w`.`grad` = 6));
```

**EDIT**

Since in both sub-expressions you're checking for `w.grad = 6` this might also be simplified into

```
  ...
  AND w.grad = 6
  AND (cw.uid_local = 2 OR cw.uid_local = 395)
```

Or even further simplified into

```
  ...
  AND w.grad = 6
  AND cw.uid_local IN (2, 395)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we rewrite your query, we get (amongst other things) the following:

```
AND cw.uid_local = 2 
AND cw.uid_local = 395
```

Unless uid_local occupies some sort of quantum state, this is unlikely to be successful.

FWIW, I find this (slightly) easier to read...

```
SELECT p.uid
  FROM tx_myext_domain_model_product p
  JOIN tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung w
    ON p.uid = w.product
  JOIN sys_category_record_mm ck
    ON p.uid = ck.uid_foreign
  JOIN sys_category_record_mm cc
    ON p.uid = cc.uid_foreign
  JOIN sys_category_record_mm cw
    ON w.uid = cw.uid_foreign
 WHERE p.season IN(1,'')
   AND p.type = "herbizid"
   AND ck.uid_local = 2
   AND ck.tablenames = "tx_myest_domain_model_product"
   AND ck.fieldname = "culture"
   AND cw.uid_local IN (2, 395, 257)
   AND cw.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_productwirkung"
   AND cc.tablenames = "tx_myext_domain_model_product"
   AND cc.fieldname = "chemicals"
   AND w.grad = 6;
```